# Compare two files with first column matching text and 2nd column of first file > than 2nd column value of 2nd file

Tags: awk, compare, multiple-columns

Looking for an awk one liner:

I have two files each with two columns

I need to print records where the first column  match in both files
and where the second file value column is > than the first file value column.

file1

```
AAAA 322
BBBB 322
DDDD 200
```

file2

```
AAAA 700
CCCC 400
DDDD 100
```

Looking for result

```
AAAA 700
```

Appreciate any help. So far I can match the column 1 but not sure how to calculate the second value column when it's >

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' file1.txt file2.txt
AAAA 700
DDDD 100
```

***updated***

I think I may have gotten it by reversing the file order and using:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt|awk '$3 > $2' |awk '{print $1" "$3}'
AAAA 700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file1
AAAA 322
BBBB 322
DDDD 200

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file2
AAAA 700
CCCC 400
DDDD 100
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1] = $2; next}($1 in A) && $2 > A[$1]' file1 file2
AAAA 700
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next}{ print $0, a[$1]}' file2.txt file1.txt|awk '$3 > $2' |awk '{print $1" "$3}'
AAAA 700
```

this achieved the output I was after